# Jquery slide toggle and append not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't seem to be getting this right. Is my syntax off? I can't seem to understand jQuery. Alert works but not these. Is there something I need to do to accommodate for these? What do I need to do to make sure these run as they don't

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    ('p').addClass('.red');
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    $('img').slideToggle;
  });
  
  $()
});
```

```css
body * {
  outline: 1px dotted palevioletred;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.row {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.click {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  margin: 25px;
}

button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="top_row">
    <div class="top_left click">
      <button id="button1">Add Class</button>
    </div>
    <div class="top_right content">
      <h1>Add Class</h1>
      <p class="blue">Click the button to add class 'red' to this paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle_row">
    <div class="middle_left click">
      <button id="button2">Sidetoggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="middle_right content">
      <h1>SideToggle</h1>
      <p>Click the button to slidetoggle a hidden image.</p>
      <img src="bayBridge.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom_row">
    <div class="bottom_left click">
      <button id="button3">Append</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_right content">
      <h1>Append</h1>
      <p>Click the button to append a new paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error here : `('p').addClass('.red');`

If you want to select all `<p>` tag the syntax is : `$('p')` (See documentation [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_selectors.asp))

If you want to add a class using addClass, you can see in the documentation [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) that you only have to add your css class, no need to use the `.` (which is used to the selector of `class` like `$('.className')`)

So change  `('p').addClass('.red');` to `$('p').addClass('red');` and all your `<p>` will be red if you click your button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $('p').addClass('red');
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    $('img').slideToggle;
  });
  
  $()
});
```

```css
body * {
  outline: 1px dotted palevioletred;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.row {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.click {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  margin: 25px;
}

button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="top_row">
    <div class="top_left click">
      <button id="button1">Add Class</button>
    </div>
    <div class="top_right content">
      <h1>Add Class</h1>
      <p class="blue">Click the button to add class 'red' to this paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle_row">
    <div class="middle_left click">
      <button id="button2">Sidetoggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="middle_right content">
      <h1>SideToggle</h1>
      <p>Click the button to slidetoggle a hidden image.</p>
      <img src="bayBridge.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom_row">
    <div class="bottom_left click">
      <button id="button3">Append</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_right content">
      <h1>Append</h1>
      <p>Click the button to append a new paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What about the toggle?

Comment: @Rin What it exactly your question ? :)